# Need to download a binary file as an excel in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blob

The issue is I want to download the response of the backend to the excel file and the response recognized as binary by talend API
here is my code

```js
function get_excels(type, id) {
  $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: URL+id+"/"+type+"/excel",
      success: function (result) {
          var blob = new Blob([result], {
              type: "application/json",
          });
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          console.log(link.href);
          link.download = `excel.xlsx`;
          link.click();
      },
  });
}
```

```html
<i onclick="get_excels('transactions', 1)" class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>
```

[image: Here is the talend API response]

[image: And here is the result of the GET method]

When I download the file, Microsoft excel throws this error [image: picture]

I need to know how can I handle the response from the API and download It as an excel file.
I will appreciate it If you can help me out.

Comment: Did you check this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993292/how-to-save-xlsx-data-to-file-as-a-blob

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit Yes but it throws an error which I should solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to read the ajax content and then download it, you can let the browser directly download it which will handle both the filename and the extension - this is also more time/memory efficient.

```
function get_excels(type, id) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = URL+id+"/"+type+"/excel"
  a.download = true // the browser will download the file and name it as the original file name and extension
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  document.body.removeChild(a)
}
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong. The result of the ajax request is what I need to download!
not the link which you mentioned! The result of the get method is the file I have.

Comment: @NiazEstefaie what are you supposed to get from URL+id+"/"+type+"/excel" when you request it?

Comment: It supposes to get the excel file from the API