# Download XLSX via Axios from Express.js server does not work

Tags: javascript, express, axios, download, xlsx

Server:

```
return res.download(filepath);
```

Client:

```
function provideDownload(filename, data) {
  const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
  linkElement.setAttribute('href', data);
  linkElement.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(linkElement);
  linkElement.click();
  linkElement.remove();
}

function provideBlobDownload(filename, data) {
  provideDownload(
    filename,
    window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]))
  );
}

axios.post('/export', {
  entity, fileformat, locale: props.locale,
}).then((res) => {
  provideBlobDownload(filename, res.data);
});
```

Problem:

Can't open downloaded xlsx file. Message: File might be corrupted.

API response in browser console looks like:

```
UEsDBAoAAAAAAPC1eVTWknwRWgEAAFoBAAARAAAAZG9jU....
```

I have already read through related posts including this one [How to save .xlsx data to file as a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993292/how-to-save-xlsx-data-to-file-as-a-blob) but I couldn't solve it.

I'd like to solve it without using an additional package like exceljs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `responseType:'blob'` to request config option:

```
axios.post('/export', {
    entity,
    fileformat,
    locale: props.locale
}, {
    responseType: 'blob'
})
.then((res) => {
    provideBlobDownload(filename, res.data);
});
```

Comment: so no one makes this mistake make sure this is outside of headers, i included inside headers and that did not work, headers: {...} , responseType: 'blob'

Comment: @JesseBoyd
Your Comment saved my time