# How can I download a generated Excel file from a POST request?

Tags: javascript, post, download

I use this code to download a file generated by a AJAX POST request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url, 
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: (result) => {
            let blob = new Blob([result]);
            let link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "inventory.xlsx";
            link.click();                
        }
    });
```

When I run that POST query using `wget`, I get a valid Excel file. However, when running above code, the resulting downloaded file is corrupt. Apperently 'something' happens in that JavaScript code, but what?

How can I download a generated Excel file from a POST request?

To give an idea of the differences, I did a `diff` using `meld` (right is javascript, left is `wget`):

[image]

Comment: can you try with adding one more attribute dataType:"blob" in your existing request code? like $.ajax({dataType:"blob" ...

Comment: Have you considered using `fetch` since this is more modern way of making ajax calls?

Comment: and one more thing just to make sure ... did you check the network tab in the chrome developer tools? you can see the actual http request performed and the response given. Maybe the CORS is triggering?

Comment: @ShaileshJadav not `dataType` but `responseType: 'blob'` you mean?

Comment: @mandy8055 tried `responseType: 'blob'`, no difference

Comment: @DiegoD no CORS is triggered. I do get about the correct amount of data back. When doing a `diff` I can see it adds bytes.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yes you got right but with ajax dataType options to same to expect data in blob.

Comment: there are some further hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993292/how-to-save-xlsx-data-to-file-as-a-blob) on SO. Anyway you may try adding two things: 1. Specify the mime type when you create the Blob by doing `let blob = new Blob([result], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});` 2. try adding `xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'},` to the object you pass to the `ajax` function. You discussed this second point with a commenter before but it wasn't exact as a nested thing of `xhrFields`

Comment: @DiegoD that `xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'}` did the trick. You could make it an answer ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly process the response given as a blob, inside the object you are passing to the `$.ajax` call, add the following property:

```
xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'}
```

### [jQuery.ajax([ settings ])](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`settings` supports a property called `xhrFields`

> An object of fieldName-fieldValue pairs to set on the native XHR
> object. For example, you can use it to set withCredentials to true for
> cross-domain requests if needed.

Those fields are expected to be passed to the native `XMLHttpRequest` object which has the `responseType` property to be set as `'blob'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

`responseType = 'blob'`

> The response is a Blob object containing the binary data.