# How to save Draft.js data using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, draftjs

I have searched high and low. But, I did found how to `convertToRaw` and `convertFromRaw`. That's great but, how to send the raw data with GraphQL?

**Option 1:**

First thing came to mind, just use `JSON.stringify(..)`, create a `GraphQLString` and send it. Boom! Done! Well...not so. If I went that route, GraphQL expects the value to be in double quotes and I got error about `unexpected token '` etc.

**Option 2:**

Send it and with `GraphQLInputObjectType`. That would work but...you have to write out all those keys in the `blocks` array. Nope! My 6th sense tells me there is a better way with `JSON.stringify(..)`, but...how?

Here's a visual representation of what the data looks like with used `convertToRaw`:
[image]

String that was passed to `GraphQLString`:

```
"{"entityMap":{},"blocks":[{"key":"7iq9s","text":"This is the type of text to pass to db via GraphQL","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}]}"
```

> "Syntax Error GraphQL request (29:36) Expected :,

Without `convertToRaw`:

```
{"entityMap":{},"blockMap":{"bk8ro":{"key":"bk8ro","type":"unstyled","text":"This is the type of text to pass to db via GraphQL","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}}},"selectionBefore":{"anchorKey":"bk8ro","anchorOffset":0,"focusKey":"bk8ro","focusOffset":0,"isBackward":false,"hasFocus":true},"selectionAfter":{"anchorKey":"bk8ro","anchorOffset":50,"focusKey":"bk8ro","focusOffset":50,"isBackward":false,"hasFocus":true}}
```

Comment: "I got error about unexpected token ' etc." Where is it happen? Can you show full code how your pass json string to graphQL client?

Comment: Hi sure, when I get back I'll make edit. Should have done that from the beginning. Sorry

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov Hi. I have now made the edit

Comment: Strange behaviour. Is it happen only with draft.js raw object? Will it work if you stringify simple object like `{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }` and pass it to graphQL client?

Comment: Yea still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I can answer this question after some research. This answer uses [atob() and btoa()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854103/why-were-javascript-atob-and-btoa-named-like-that).

To pass a value to a `GraphQLString's` args, ie, `content`:

1. Convert Draft.js with `convertToRaw`
2. JSON.stringify() the result
3. Use btoa()

That way you'll end up with a very long string: `Q29udGVudFN0YXRlIHsgImVudGl0eU1hcCI6IFtvYmplY3QgT2JqZWN0...etc`

To decode, use `atob()`, JSON.parse()`then`convertFromRaw`. There maybe an easier way but for now, this works. Im sure these steps can be reduced.