# PHP base64 encode post request

Tags: php, html, base64, encode

**In short:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="foo">bar</textarea>
</form>
```

I want to POST value of `foo` as base64 encoded (without using ajax to save time).

**In detail:**

- I have a interface where people can fire SQL SELECT queries to get the simple reports.
- Network(Company firewall) filters the POST request considering it as SQL Injection.
- One solution I can think of is to encode the data and then make the POST request. Then decode on server side.
- Any way to not use ajax [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854103/why-were-javascript-atob-and-btoa-named-like-that)? That will help me avoid the refactoring of the code.

Comment: 1. How can the firewall treat all POST as SQL injection, it makes no sense and makes internet unusable. 2. You need to use HTTPS!

Comment: What's your _actual_ question? This reads like a train of thought. What does SQL have to do with this? What does AJAX have to do with it? You want to POST a base64 value? What's stopping you?

Comment: It's not possible without JS. Use HTTPS, the firewall won't manage to spy on the request.

Comment: @emix unless they use a custom certificate to MITM all the connections Many enterprises do that.

Comment: @Dharman not all but randomly some queries are filtered. May be some pattern in query that gets matched.

Comment: Legacy Code. It's an internal application. Still not using https. Have planned to shift to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Ajax, You can use form's `onsubmit` event to write a javascript handler, that encodes the data to hidden input, which gets sent along with the form (note that the original textarea has no `name`, so it won't be sent in POST).

```
function encodeSql() {

    var e = document.getElementById('sql');
    var t = document.getElementById('sql_base64');
    t.value = encodeToBase64Somehow(e.value);
    return true;
}

<form ... onsubmit="return encodeSql()">
    <textarea id="sql">...</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="sql_base64" id="sql_base64" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nice! I will try this.

Comment: [Googlian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365036/861704) answer to encode.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the text value to Base64 string before submit the form without using Ajax using `window.btoa`

```
var str = document.getElementById("foo").value;
var enc = window.btoa(str);
```

> The `btoa()` method encodes a string in base-64.
>   This method uses the "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9", "+", "/" and "=" characters to encode the string.

For more information related to the `btoa` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa